# Basic usage of GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm struggling to understand the use of `GROUP BY` in this query and am looking for clarification:

```
Flights(flno: integer, from: string, to: string, distance: integer, departs: time, arrives: time, price: real)
Aircraft(aid: integer, aname: string, cruisingrange: integer)
Certified(eid: integer, aid: integer)
Employees(eid: integer, ename: string, salary: integer)
```

The question is: For all aircraft with cruising range over 1000 miles, find the name of the aircraft and the average salary of all pilots certified for this aircraft.

```
SELECT Temp.name, Temp.AvgSalary
FROM ( SELECT A.aid, A.aname AS name,
              AVG (E.salary) AS AvgSalary
       FROM Aircraft A, Certified C, Employees E
       WHERE A.aid = C.aid AND
             C.eid = E.eid AND A.cruisingrange > 1000
       GROUP BY A.aid, A.aname ) AS Temp
```

Why is the `GROUP BY` necessary here? Wouldn't the following query return the aircraft and the corresponding salary, or would it return the average salary of all employees not specific to each aircraft?

```
       SELECT A.aname, AVG(E.salary)
       FROM Aircraft A, Certified C, Employees E
       WHERE A.aid = C.aid AND
             C.eid = E.eid AND A.cruisingrange > 1000
```

Does using `GROUP BY` change the format of the table so that using `GROUP BY A.aid` would specify that we are only grouping the aircraft table and leaving the certified and employee tables untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GROUP BY is required to preform aggregation (in this case, taking the average) properly.

If you don't group by anything, MySQL will preform this aggregation over your entire table. In other words, if you used your last query it will return the average salary for all aircraft with a cruising range over 1000, with no distinction of which aircraft is which. Try it, and you will see this behavior.

However, if you use the `GROUP BY` clause here, you will see the average for each *individual* aircraft with a cruising range over 1000, which is what you want. Without it, you're taking the average of *all* aircraft.

Try these queries on some sample data, and the difference in behavior will become much more clear.

---

**EDIT**

Regarding your last few statements: yes, we are not doing anything with the certified or employee table. To step back, the problem states *for each aircraft*. Many times, if you are given a problem statement that spells out for which group of items you need results, it is a good start to place that as your group by clause.

Comment: @tryingtolearn not a problem! I can't stress enough that, if you have some sample data, you should try both queries. If you are a visual learner, seeing the result difference between the two queries will make it much easier to understand as well.

Comment: Definitely. Can you recommend any good websites that allow me to quickly set up tables and visualize the results of queries?

Comment: Www.sqlfiddle.com is one of the best websites for what you want. I use it all the time to help people on stack.

Answer (score 1):

it is kind of instinct when writing AVG(...) in SQL, use GROUP BY to specify the criteria you want as defining the group of average.
withough GROUP BY clause, it will only group all E.salary and make an average.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you select aggregate functions like AVG, SUM, MAX, MIN, etc... alongside other columns, you must group by all columns which are not aggregate functions or constants.  The only exception to this I can think of is when you use windowing functions (not available in MySQL).

In this example, I'm unclear as to why the `a.aid` is not selected from `Temp`.  If there are two Aircraft with the same name but different ids, you could see results like...

```
aname   avg
------  -------
747     100,000
747     110,000
DC10     90,000
```

...where the two records are for different aircraft with the same name (747)

The group by here says to average the salaries per aircraft, giving you the average salaries per aircraft...as in only include salaries for the aircraft you're finding the average for.

Comment: The a.aid is taken at the end though because of the "A.aid, A.aname AS name," statement. Thank you for your explanation!